# Excel VSTO set selection

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, selection

How do I set the selection in the active worksheet to a specific Range, using C# and VSTO 2008?

Comment: What actualy u wanna do ? i m not getting your questions.do u need to change the  values of specific ranges ??

Comment: I probably meant I want to change the currently selected cells to a specific range. That is after my code is executed, I want to have some cells (in a range) selected!

Answer (score 2):

```
Range currentCells = activeSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1"); 
currentCells.Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
currentCells.Activate();
```